# XPM FootPrint not overriding current claims

Tags: smarttarget, ambient-data-framework

I have created a simple footprint based on browser type. I have verified that every time when I was selecting the footprint it was showing the same claim store and there was no change in triggers. Can anyone suggest what I am missing or where can I look to get the root cause..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely reason is that it is not whitelisted in cd_ambient_conf.xml. You will need to make sure that the IP and the user account (if applicable) is whitelisted -- as well as the new claim.

For more information, have a look at the following pages in the SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 documentation:

- [Configuring which claims the Web service accepts](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-3512166E-CFB6-4DC2-8B83-49689D62A779)
- [Configuring which accounts can send cookies with Claims](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-9721A255-15D3-4490-8DB6-8AA39AB3BA0D)
- [Configuring a whitelist of IP addresses from which cookies may be sent](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-2234AA23-E736-45F3-8242-7BA26EED4E38)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the footprint cartridge configured in your ambient data configuration, as per step 9 of [Quick Guide to installing Experience Manager (Session Preview)](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-3C70F892-69F4-4FEE-922D-39F1AFEBD539)?

Answer (score 1):

Mukesh as  Peter and Devid suggested please check your cd_ambient_conf.xml file. But before you move to the detail check just verify once again have you updated your claim into that cd_ambient_conf.xml file under the GloballyAcceptedClaims node ?

[For more detail check here](https://justsayantan.wordpress.com/2015/07/12/create-custom-footprints-in-experience-manager/)