# Default Footprints are not working in my DD4T based Application

Tags: experience-manager, footprint

I can see different promotions based on my browser,so promotions are working fine but while i am trying to see my Firefox promotions on chrome using footprint, they are not changing.
My cd_ambient_Cartridge.xml consist footprint cartridge i.e

```
<Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml"/>
 <Cartridge File="footprint_cartridge_conf.xml"/>
```

Comment: See [@Peter's answer to a similar question](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/12560/46). You may need to configure  claims, accounts, and/or white-listed IP addresses if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Global Accepted Claims were missing earlier. thanks

Comment: Nice. You can note your change in an answer (maybe set to community, up to you) and accept. This will help others find the solution in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Global accepted claims worked.

```
 <GloballyAcceptedClaims>
       <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:sessioncartridge:useragent:browser"/>
       <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:footprintcartridge:acceptlanguage"/>
       <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:footprintcartridge:recurringvisitor"/>
       <Claim Uri="taf:claim:ambientdata:sessioncartridge:useragent:os"/>
       ....
       <Claim Uri="taf:claim:audiencemanager:contact:extendeddetail:age"/>
    </GloballyAcceptedClaims>
```